# Is the state returned from the useReducer Hook a "deep copy" or a reference of a reducers output?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I'm currently implementing global state handling in React using the Context API in combination with the `useReducer` hook.

I have two concerns regarding mutability:

- When updating state in my reducers, do I need to e.g use Lodash's `cloneDeep` function to sever the reference between the objects going into my reducer and the stored state?
- Is it possible to ruin the global state by manually mutating it outside reducers, or will it behave like "normal React state" in the sense that manual mutations will get overwritten during the next update cycle?

For reference: [docs](http://When%20updating%20state%20in%20my%20reducers,%20do%20I%20need%20to%20take%20object%20references%20into%20account,%20and%20e.g%20use%20Lodash's%20%60cloneDeep%60%20function%20to%20sever%20the%20reference%20between%20the%20objects%20going%20into%20my%20reducer/state?)

Answer (score 1):

Both `useState` and `useReducer` give you the exact value reference that you saved (either by calling `someSetter(newValue)`, or returning a value from the reducer function).

In either case, manually mutating the value is wrong.  In particular, both of them will bail out of updates if you return the identical reference as last time, so you should always update values immutably.

Answer (score -3):

I would give this a read.

https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively

This is a really good guide of how to use react context in conjunction with `useReducer` the right way.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Link-only answer... Without the outlink, the answer is effectively meaningless.